# Why Notification works with NSHourCalendarUnit but not with NSWeekCalendarUnit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, notifications, nsdate

I don't understand why `LocalNotification` would work flawlessly with NSHourCalendarUnit but never ever with `NSWeekCalendarUnit` and `NSDayCalendarUnit` although it shows the correct time in the log!! There must be something I'm missing when the setting the `weekday` I need it to fire on.. What would it be?

Please have a look on my code the log came out so you can guide to the mistake I'm doing:

```
-(void) Monday {   // 9th Notification Every 1:35

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

components.weekday = 2;
components.hour   = 10;
components.minute = 56;
components.second = 35;

NSDate *fire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"The Fire Day is:: %@", fire);


UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
if (notif == nil)
    return;

notif.fireDate = fire;
notif.repeatInterval= NSWeekCalendarUnit ;
notif.soundName = @"ring.wav";
notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"THANKS for Your HELP :)"] ;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif] ;

NSLog(@"*****NEW LOG Notification Details*****%@", notif);
}
```

and here is the log:

```
2014-01-20 10:09:12.935 daily notification test[17591:c07] The Fire Day is:: 2014-01-20 10:10:35 +0000
```

****LOG UPDATE:****

```
2014-01-20 10:56:21.694 daily notification test[17823:c07] The Fire Day is:: 2014-01-20 10:56:35 +0000
2014-01-20 10:56:21.697 daily notification test[17823:c07] *****NEW LOG Notification Details*****<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x7180360>{fire date = Monday, January 20, 2014, 11:56:35 AM Central European Standard Time, time zone = (null), repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Monday, January 20, 2014, 11:56:35 AM Central European Standard Time, user info = (null)}
.
```

2014-01-20 10:56:21.694 daily notification test[17823:c07] The Fire Day is:: 2014-01-20 10:56:35 +0000
2014-01-20 10:56:21.697 daily notification test[17823:c07] *****NEW LOG Notification Details*****{fire date = Monday, January 20, 2014, 11:56:35 AM Central European Standard Time, time zone = (null), repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Monday, January 20, 2014, 11:56:35 AM Central European Standard Time, user info = (null)}

Comment: Note that you can NSLog the notification itself to get information about when it will fire.

Comment: @MartinR How? is it different than the one I'm using already?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", notif)` prints the "next fire date" as calculated by UILocalNotification. It is just a suggestion that *might* help to solve your problem.

Comment: How would you go about your first point @MartinR?

Comment: @MartinR that's an amazing piece of info worth the correct answer. Thank you.. I have updated my Q with the new log info to see if you or anyone can help me find the mystery

Comment: @user1949873: If you have problems with NSWeekCalendarUnit/NSDayCalendarUnit then you should show the code and NSLog output for *that* case, and not for NSHourCalendarUnit (which - as you say - is working flawlessly).

Comment: @MartinR if you notice that's exactly what I'm doing :) here in my code I'm using `NSDayCalendarUnit` which it logs exactly as `NSWeekCalendarUnit` however I'll update that and show you the log in a sec

Comment: @MartinR check the question, I have updated the code and the log.. and with `NSHourCalendarUnit` I mean it as an `NSDateComponents` not as a `repeatinterval` only

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
notif.repeatInterval= NSHourCalendarUnit ;
```

with

```
notif.repeatInterval= NSWeekCalendarUnit;
```

Edited

Try this one now , it may help

```
NSCalendar *gregorian1 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        [gregorian1 setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

        NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [gregorian1 components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate new]];

        [nowComponents setWeekday:2]; //Monday
       [nowComponents setWeek: [nowComponents week] + 1]; //Next week
        [nowComponents setHour:8]; //8a.m.
       [nowComponents setMinute:0];
        [nowComponents setSecond:0];

        NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian1 dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
```

Comment: I have updated that..still not working :/ check the question again please.. it's actually with `NSDateComponent` the problem

Comment: I have edited my answer , try it once and let me know if it solved your purpose .

Comment: Yes surely this will automatically work for same time next week .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just set a `weekday` in `NSDateComponents` without adjusting the `day`
accordingly. This calculation should work:

```
NSInteger wantedWeekday = 2; // Monday
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
                       fromDate:[NSDate date]];

components.day += wantedWeekday - components.weekday;
components.weekday = wantedWeekday;
components.hour   = 8;
components.minute = 10;
components.second = 35;
NSDate *fire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

This calculates a date on either the previous or the next Monday, but that does not
matter. If `fire` is in the past, `UILocalNotification` will correct that automatically.

*Remark:* `NSLog(@"%@", aNotification)` shows the next fire date as calculated by
`UILocalNotification`. This can be helpful to diagnose problems.